# While running webdriver IO codes returning Object Promises

Tags: async-await, webdriver-io-v4

```js
get verifyText(){
    return $(".uU7dJb");
}
       
async loadText(){
    var Elem;
    Elem = (await this.verifyText).getText();
    console.log("  " +Elem);
}
```

**running above code not returning Element text  instead it returning " [object Promise]" **

Comment: `Elem = await (await this.verifyText()).getText();`